# Extruding vertices along normal

Tags: mesh, vertices, extrude

I'm facing this problem: I want to extrude the 4 vertices of a plane along the normal to the face.

The operations I perform are:

· Add > Mesh > Cube

· Scale > X > 0

· Merge > By Distance

· Delete > only Edges and Faces

· Extrude > X

As you can see from the screenshot when selecting X I'm not able to see any extrusion, while it works if I do on Z or Y.

Any clue of the problem?

I'm using OSX, Blender 3.1.

Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are scaling a cube by 0 that means that any coordinate on X axis will be 0,

because `any value x 0 = 0`. Scale cube in edit mode.